# change input text value with angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a basic input which is displaying timestamp in milliseconds, which is saved on the scope.

However, I want it to display formatted time, and I dont want to store new variable.

I am looking for a solution like this:

```
ng-model="parseTime(timestamp)"
```

And in controller:

```
$scope.parseTime = function(systemTime) {
    var time = new Date(systemTime);       
    return time.toDateString();
};
```

Comment: You cannot use a function call because ng-model uses two-way binding. So if you change the view, Angular would change the underlying model accordingly. I'm afraid you'll have to use a scope variable ... or one-way binding like `value="{{parseTime(timestamp)}}"`

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but the function isnt being called..

Comment: It should be (see plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Z1nWnzv8agGeu4OHQnVy?p=preview ). You should take into account that the `value` of an input element is always of type `string`, so you should `parseInt` it first

Answer (score 0):

Is is not possible, You can do it by using watch

```
$scope.$watch('timestamp', function(value) {
  if (value) {
    var time = new Date(value);       
    $scope.timestamp= time.toDateString();
  }
});
```

html should be

```
ng-model="timestamp"
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but won't that create an endless loop? You watch timestamp changes and then you change timestamp inside the callback ... which triggers a change event for timestamp and so on

Comment: @devnull69 yes you are correct..it'll goes to infinite loop